# Cambiar formato de fecha dentro de query C#

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo el siguiente `query`:

```
SELECT ca.cod_parte,
       pa.descripcion,
       ca.rollo,
       ma.fecha AS fechaIngreso,
       pa.unidad,
       ca.cantidad
FROM Casiller ca
INNER JOIN Partes pa ON pa.cod_parte=ca.cod_parte
INNER JOIN Det_materiales dt ON dt.rollo=ca.rollo
INNER JOIN Materiales ma ON ma.factura=dt.factura
WHERE ca.cod_parte='3141.39' AND ca.cantidad>0
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Lo cual me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En C# estoy usando el mismo query pero usando EF:

```
//LISTADO DE NO ROLLOS SEGUN SU PARTE
        public List<mapeoRollos> listadoRollos(string cod)
        {
            var lista = new List<mapeoRollos>();

            using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
            {
                var query = from ca in ctx.Casillers
                            join pa in ctx.Partes on ca.cod_parte equals pa.cod_parte
                            join dt in ctx.Det_materiales on ca.rollo equals dt.rollo
                            join ma in ctx.Materiales on dt.factura equals ma.factura
                            where ca.cod_parte == cod && ca.cantidad > 0
                            orderby ma.fecha descending
                            select new mapeoRollos
                            {
                                rollo=ca.rollo,
                                descripcion=pa.descripcion,
                                fecha=ma.fecha,
                                unidad=pa.unidad,
                                disponible=ca.cantidad
                            };

                lista = query.ToList();           
            }

            return lista;
        }
```

**MAPEO**

```
public class mapeoRollos
    {
        public string rollo { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
        public string unidad { get; set; }
        public double disponible { get; set; }

    }
```

Me devuelve lo mismo que lo anterior asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo formatear la fecha de forma que se vea un "poco mejor" en lugar de eso con "T0000000"?(intente usar .toDateShortString... pero el linq no lo permite)

Comment: ¿puedes poner el detalle de la clase mapeoRollos?. punto aparte: en vista html la columna unidad muestra la fecha y fecha de ingreso muestra unidad.

Comment: @patovega listo, mapeoRollos agregado

Comment: ¿el problema no sera en la vista? cuando debugeas, ¿que valor toma ma.fecha en la variable lista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes utilizar SqlFunctions.DateName para formatear fecha (para formato dd/mm/yyyy) y como ma.fecha es datetime es probable que siga agregando la hora como T00:00:00, cambialo a string.

```
select new mapeoRollos
                    {
                        rollo = ca.rollo,
                        descripcion = pa.descripcion,
                        //fecha=ma.fecha,
                        fecha = SqlFunctions.DateName("day", ma.fecha) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("month", ma.fecha) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("year", ma.fecha)
                        unidad = pa.unidad,
                        disponible = ca.cantidad
                    };
```